# How catch a "dynamic" id in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like catch a ID when i hover another id dynamically to hidden or inline the div when hover

My function to create HTML and ID

```
function addImages(images,line) {
var html =  '<img id="box-' + image.name + '" class="relative absolute mx-auto text-center imgPaste h-'+ image.height +'to2" src="img/'+image.name+'.'+image.extension+'" alt="'+image.description+'"/>' +
    '<a id="want-it-'+ image.name +'" href="img/'+image.name+'.'+image.extension+'" style="top:'+ TopAbsolute +'" target="_blank" class="hidden absolute z-50 absolute-js border-2 h-8 w-8 rounded-full font-black text-gray-200">' + '+' + '</a>';
$('#line-' + line).append(html);        }
```

my function to catch id -> the problem is here how i can take one dynamic id without the others id ?

```
$('img[id^="box-"]').mouseenter(function(){
$("#want-it-' + image.name +'"]').removeClass("hidden")     });
```

Comment: You have an error in `$("#want-it-' + image.name +'"]')` should be `$("#want-it-'" + image.name +"']")`

Comment: wtff really :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bind event with `$('img[id^="box-"]').mouseenter(function() { ... })` it will only bind events for `elements` which are `already exists`. For dynamically created `elements` it will not work.

You will need to have `delegate binding` which will have syntax like `$(document).on('mouseenter', 'img[id^="box-"]', function() { ... })`.

Moreover I have updated one line to replace `image.name` with `let imageName = this.id.replace('box-', '');` inside `mouseenter`.

You can check result below.

```js
let TopAbsolute = 10;

function addImages(image, line) {
  var html = '<img id="box-' + image.name + '" class="relative absolute mx-auto text-center imgPaste h-' + image.height + 'to2" src="img/' + image.name + '.' + image.extension + '" alt="' + image.description + '"/>' + '<a id="want-it-' + image.name + '" href="img/' + image.name + '.' + image.extension + '" style="top:' + TopAbsolute + '" target="_blank" class="hidden absolute z-50 absolute-js border-2 h-8 w-8 rounded-full font-black text-gray-200">' + '+' + '</a>';
  $('#line-' + line).append(html);
}

$(document).on('mouseenter', 'img[id^="box-"]', function() {
  let imageName = this.id.replace('box-', '');  
  $("#want-it-" + imageName).removeClass("hidden");
  console.log('mouse enter');
});

let image = {
  name: 'xyz',
  height: 10,
  extension: 'jpeg',
  description: 'xyz',
};

addImages(image, 1);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.absolute {
  height: 100;
  width: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="line-1"></div>
```

Comment: THANKS U BRO U CONTRIBUTE AT MY PROGRESSION LOVE YOU <3

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `id` of the image you click on then use something like this:

```
function addImages(images, line) {
  var html = '<img id="box-' + image.name + '" class="relative absolute mx-auto text-center imgPaste h-' + image.height + 'to2" src="img/' + image.name + '.' + image.extension + '" alt="' + image.description + '"/>' +
    '<a id="want-it-' + image.name + '" href="img/' + image.name + '.' + image.extension + '" style="top:' + TopAbsolute + '" target="_blank" class="hidden absolute z-50 absolute-js border-2 h-8 w-8 rounded-full font-black text-gray-200">' + '+' + '</a>';
  $('#line-' + line).append(html);
}

$('img[id^="box-"]').mouseenter(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id").replace('box-', '') // <-Changed
  $("#want-it-'" + id + "']").removeClass("hidden") // <-Changed
});
```

I've changed some code in your `mouseenter` event, so it gets the `id` from the clicked element and remove the `box-` from the id.